# Perl best practices: file parser using regexes and database storage

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I'm writing a log file parser in Perl, using regexes that I've stored in a database. My workflow is basically like this:

- Looping over the file and searching
  for patterns matching my regexes and
  then extract them
- Do something with these matches
- Store them accordingly in a database

Last time I did this I explicitly wrote each regex (not looping through each regex in the database), [like this](http://code.google.com/p/codalyzer/source/browse/trunk/parser/Parser.pm).

Now that I'm doing this again I was wondering if there were better solutions out there, better yet comments on what I've already done.

Thanks! =)

Comment: That's quite a lot of code. Can you excerpt a small snippet that demonstrates the approach you are taking?

Comment: Certainly, this is what I did last time: 

http://code.google.com/p/codalyzer/source/browse/trunk/parser/Parser.pm

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [`Regexp::Assemble`](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Assemble).

It will let you compose 1 regex that matches all of your regexes. It also claims it can track which of the original patterns the match corresponds too. I have not used this package before, though.

Comment: Looks great, I'll check it out. =)

Comment: I have used it, it's great. See also: command line tool [`assemble`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Assemble/eg/assemble) (not installed by default) and the improved [`Regexp::Assemble::Compressed`](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Assemble::Compressed).

Comment: @Lenny Benny I also use Regexp::Assemble in my project Octopussy (which is a log management solution :) ) It's a really good module to speed up your parsing except for some cases like this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1739285/24820).